# PHP get data or interact with a running Java process. (I think different than PHP/Java bridge)

Tags: java, php, bind

I have an apache2 webserver with php installed and working. I am wondering if there is any way I can get a PHP script to access a Java program that is constantly running, mostly to just get information that the process keeps track of.  The Java program is not a webapp or running within the apache server.  It is a separate program.

Ive been looking into PHP/Java Bridge systems, and all they seem to do is let you run Java programs from PHP and vice-a-versa, which is not what I need.  I can think of a way to do this via a web service and SOAP running on localhost, but if there is a way to avoid this and I can gain direct access to the Java program, I could get my webapp to run much faster.

The Java app that I am trying to "talk to" is a program that I wrote so I have access to the source code to make the necessary changes if something within the Java program needs to be set up.

Thanks in advance, I've been looking all over for something like this.

Comment: Would using something like RabbitMQ work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP/Java Bridges let you call a running Java program from PHP.

Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP/Java_Bridge

Read: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php

The bridges actually use local socket communication, from the [faq](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/FAQ.html):

```
<?php
    include_once("Java.inc");

$i1 = new Java("your.class", "1");
$i2 = new Java("your.class", "2");
$i3 = $i1->add($i2);
echo $i3->toString() . "\n";
?>
```

See [Java.inc](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/php-java-bridge/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_6.2.1/exploded/Java.inc?r=http%3A%2F%2Fphp-java-bridge.sourceforge.net%2Fpjb%2Fdownload.php&ts=1298821956&use_mirror=ovh).
And edit your java code to contain the following line:

```
static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner = php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance("9267");
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to communicate with the Java process in one way or another. As a web service is too heavy, you could simply communicate over a socket with a custom text or binary protocol.

Or you could also perhaps make the Java program write to a database every n seconds, and read from the database in your PHP script.

EDIT :

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php for a socket client example in PHP.

Look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html for a server socket example in Java.

Comment: I had thought about using a database as a fallback, but I would like to try to get it working in as real time as possible.  Ill look into socket programming.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is possible to use a socket to communicate within the same machine, I just need to open a socket to localhost and a consistent port number within both languages and they should be able to use that to communicate with each other?

Comment: The server socket must be created on a dedicated port number (choose it between 2000 and 60000, for example 4444, and make sure no other application uses this port). The client socket connects to localhost, on port 4444, and is bound by the OS to a random available port. You might thus even have lots of clients for the same server, on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, so basically you need to run java application from php and get response from java application?

If its that so - I can't see any problem fro php/java-bridge. For example I've successfully run java encryption method for custom encryption in php.

Comment: No. The OP sais that the Java program was constantly running, and keeping track of some information. He even said he didn't want to run Java from PHP or vice-versa.

Comment: No I have a java program that is running constantly and I need to access it from a php script that would be run when a page is loaded to pull the latest information.

Comment: oh, yeah :) In that case I stick with your suggestions. Other way around is to call php service from the java application or to call php script from java code.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into Quercus/Resin. PHP runs inside Java on a Java web server. You can call Java code as if it was PHP functions/commands. All PHP commands are not supported, both most are. For example, you can run WordPress under Quercus.
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/